# Comma Punctuation Needed or Not?

Tags: pronunciation, commas

Do I need to put a comma in the following sentence given after the word globe to avoid a run on sentence? My thinking is that as it's a dependent clause, a comma is not needed.

> The Industrial Revolution started in Europe before spreading over the globe creating economic growth and is recognized by experts as an economic first.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a complete re-write, as there are several issues with the sentence as it stands.

I would write:

> The Industrial Revolution started in Europe and then spread over the globe. It created economic growth and is recognized by experts as an economic first.

The preposition 'before' after 'started' is redundant, and the whole 'sentence' is really two sentences.

So no comma needed!